# How do I edit the PATH variable in Debian 10

Tags: environment-variables, bash

I am following the guidelines on [Debain10 Jmeter Setup](https://sarkershantonu.github.io/2021/01/06/install-jmeter-plugins-cli/) and as part of the config there is a requirement to modify environment variables, specifically the PATH variable in .profile file. I am a bit unsure if I am editing the correct file because I don't see any existing references to PATH in the file :

```
nano ~/.profile
```

The result is :
[image: .profile]

It seems the file contains no reference to PATH or least an entry for PATH. In the article above there is a requirement to also to ***Modify PATH variable at the end of the line***.
For now it appears as if the PATH variable is being maintained elsewhere.

As a check I have tried running `nano ~/bashrc` but I get the following output :
[image: Bashrc]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please rather than posting screenshots  use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" using [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. - Also you don't need to know exactly where variables are originally defined since you can modify variables that are set elsewhere in  ~/.profile a fairly typical approach would be `export PATH=$PATH:/some/extra/path`